# How to retrieve an object instance related to a Thread in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

In java I have the following generated code:

```
public class B {
    public void exec(){
        X x = (X) Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(x.value);
    }
}

public class X extends Thread{
    public int value;

    public X(int x){
        value = x;
    }
    public void run(){
        B b = new B();
        b.exec();
    }
}

new X(4).start();
```

The B exec() method retrieves the field value corresponding to the current Thread (also instance of the class X).

Is there a way to simulate the same behavior in C++? Note: I wouldn't like to pass x as a parameter to the B instance because the code is generated.

```
class B {
public:
    void exec();
};

class X {
public:
    int value;
    X(int x) {
        value = x;
    }
    void run() {
        B * b = new B();
        b->exec();
    }    
};

void B::exec() {
    std::cout << ??? << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    X * x = new X(3);
    boost::thread thr(boost::bind(&X::run, x));
    thr.join();
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve the class instance related to the thread ( I know I don't have one ), any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to pass parameters to B (which would have been the cleanest solution), you can use thread-local storage.

Looking at your code in general though, you'll probably be shooting yourself in the foot by trying this strict 1-to-1 mapping from Java to C++.

In C++, you should almost never call `new`. Allocate on the stack whenever possible. `new` in C++ is obviously error-prone (no garbage collection), but it's also extremely slow compared to managed languages like Java.

Functors can be used as a more powerful alternative to function pointers (for example when creating your thread), or just to replace generic `exec()` or `run()` functions. Name them `operator()` instead, and the class can be used as a functor.

And in your constructors you should use the initializer list as much as possible.

The following applies the above suggestions to your code. Of course I passed an argument to the B constructor. If that's not an option, use [thread local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F39%5F0/doc/html/thread/thread%5Flocal%5Fstorage.html) instead.

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(int value) : value(value)
    void operator()();

private:
    int value;
};

class X {
public:
    int value;
    X(int x) :value(x) { }// use the initializer list to initialize members

    void operator()() {
        B b(value); // allocate B on the stack if possible
        b();
    }    
};

void B::operator()() {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::thread thr(X(3));
    thr.join();
}
```

Of course in this simple example, you don't really need two classes in the first place. You could just as easily have removed `X` entirely and done:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(int value) : value(value)
    void operator()();

private:
    int value;
};

void B::operator()() {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::thread thr(B(3));
    thr.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you can't (or shouldn't) subclass `boost::thread`. You can use [thread-local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) to put your own thread-specific stuff though.

Arguably, you should use the same technique for Java code. Java has [`ThreadLocal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for that purpose.